# Is it okay to use "shadow dawns"?

Tags: word-usage

> *Now, shadows dawn as the twilight comes.*

*Dawn* has the meaning "come into existence". Does it work that way almost every time with words like, for example, *shadows*? Or, are there quite limited types of word that can be used with *dawn*? And, the sentence above, does it sound awkward to you?

Comment: There's no "grammatical rule" saying you can't do this - it's just semantically/idiomatically *weird*. I suppose some people might be more accepting if it was in a "poetic" context, but I'm not one of them. Literal sun and figurative "enlightenment" *dawn*; twilight, dusk, and shadows *creep up* or otherwise appear "stealthily".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's writing advice

Comment: I expect that this will get closed as writing advice, so I'm not going to post an answer, just a comment: I don't like the phrasing, it's counter-intuitive to have shadows dawning.  I'd recommend something like "bloom" or "grow" or "stretch".

Comment: I kind of like it, in a poetic sense.  It produces a sort of symmetry between morning and evening, which is pleasing in the right context.

Comment: Yes, it's okay. People should not feel so constrained so as to "ask permission" about possible so-called non-standard or unexpected or irregular uses. Where would English be if Shakespeare and TS Eliot and E.E. Cummings had done  that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase "shadows dawn" is not particularly apt, especially in light of your definition of dawn - "come into existence". During the day (except under conditions of heavy overcast or fog), the shadows are always there, although they are extremely short at noon.

A more common phrasing would be "shadows grow as the twilight comes". That is, shadows grow longer as the sun sinks lower in the sky.

Of course, if this is intended as a statement by a vampire, who looks forward to the coming of night as others look forward to the coming of day, it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly is out there in this piece of poetry, or whatever it is:

> [like panicked ants - pOeTrY bOoK 4](https://books.google.ca/books?id=pJtkNrpPRDgC&pg=PA47&dq=%22a%20shadow%20dawns%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TBIoVcyfIqT9sATgpYHIAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22a%20shadow%20dawns%22&f=false)  By Steve Glickman
>
> Desperately searching for the spotlight, clinging to false
>   impressions. **A shadow dawns** hard on the newest estimation; we fall in
>   line for the final time. Pointless power mongers knot knowing that the
>   trail surrounds. The center collapses without ...

Answer (score -1):

'Dawn' meaning 'come into existence' is more in the line of a metaphor for the dawn of a new day than an alternate definition.  Thus the confusion of shadows being compared to the sun in the minds of readers.

'Loom' might be a better word.